# Adding Angular application to an existing project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've got an existing project where I'd like to add an Angular application using the Angular CLI.

**The project structure looks like this right now:**

- node_modules
- src

  - client
  - server
  - shared
- .angular-cli.json
- package.json

The client and shared folders are still empty and I'd like to install my angular app inside the client folder but still I want to maintain just one package.json for the whole project. That's why I tried to add the angular-cli.json with the following content:

```
{
  "project": {
    "name": "projectname"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "./src/client",
      "outDir": "./dist/browser"
    }
  ]
}
```

**The question:**

What's the best way to add the Angular application (into /src/client) to my project now? I wasn't able to simply run `ng new` because of the existing package.json and probably it wouldn't generate the app inside the /src/client folder then either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using ng new is still the easiest way to achieve this.

1. Create an angular project using **ng new**.
2. Move everything in the src folder to src/client
3. Adjust the root property in angular-cli.json (or angular.json) to *src/client*, also if you care about linting, adjust the linting property.
4. Set the *extends* property in **tsconfig.app.json** and **tsconfig.spec.json** to "extends": "../../tsconfig.json"
5. Test serving, building, testing and linting commands. They should work fine.
6. Copy the content from the server folder and add of its dependencies to package.json

Answer (score 7):

The answer of @Austin752 seems to be outdated. According to the documentation the command to add an angular application to an existing project is (Angular CLI version 8.3.23):

```
$ ng generate application <name> [options]
```

Or

```
$ ng g application <name> [options]
```

see: https://angular.io/cli/generate#application-command

This will add the new app in the `projects` folder in the root of your workspace

Answer (score 2):

There's a parameter --directory, at least in the latest version of Angular.

So now you just run

```
ng new <app-name> --directory <dir-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently worked on a project that required this type of setup. As of Angular 7.2 simply type

```
ng g a yourNewApp
```

That will create your new application in a projects folder

To create components in a newly created application

```
ng g c view1 --project=yourNewApp
```