# Use a library in an imported angular application into multi-project structure

Tags: angular, angular-library, multi-project

I've an angular application `a-app` in `10.0.6`, but I need to include it into an angular multi-project structure. In this multi-project structure, I have a `b-app` application.

- Angular multi-project structure is working fine.
- I have created a `my-lib` library and included it into `b-app` application and it's working. I followed this procedure [Using your own library in applications](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#using-your-own-library-in-applications)
- I moved my `a-app` application into the multi-project structure and it's working! To make this work, I'm using the `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, `tsconfig.base.json`, `angular.json` from multiproject structure. And `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json` extends `../../tsconfig.base.json`.
- It means, I can run both applications `a-app` and `b-app` from multi-project structure.

Folder structure is this:

```
my-workspace/
  ...             (workspace-wide config files)
  projects/       (generated applications and libraries)
    a-app/        --(imported application manually)
      ...         --(application-specific config: karma.conf.js, tsconfig.app.json, tsconfig.spec.json)
      src/        --(source and support files for application)
    b-app/ --(an explicitly generated application)
      ...         --(application-specific config)
      src/        --(source and support files for application)
    my-lib/       --(a generated library)
      ...         --(library-specific config)
      src/        --source and support files for library)
```

But when I try to import `my-lib` in application `a-app` in the multi-project structure, it's not working!!! Just displays this error:

- `Cannot find module 'my-lib' or its corresponding type declarations`

I've modified all config files from `a-app` to be similar to `b-app`, included the `a-app` in the `angular.json`, but still not working. Practically, I did steps 3-5 from here: [Adding Angular application to an existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49694263/1133816)

What am I missing in this configuration, to make it work?

Comment: Just a suggestion: try using [NX](https://nx.dev). Angular workspaces have their limitations. For example, you cannot reference a library from another library, etc.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll take a look on it.

Comment: [Here's an example workspace](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-youtube-player) containing a yourube-api and youtube-player library + demo application.

Comment: Also another note: use the same major version number for your package as the angular version you're targetting. Eg. If your library uses `@angular/core: ^12.1.3` then give your library a version `12.x.x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... It was a mistake.

I'm using [Path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in `a-app` application which means that I had configured the `paths` property in `tsconfig.app.json` inside `a-app`.

With that configuration, the `a-app` didn't extend the `paths` property in `tsconfig.base.json`, therefore, it couldn't find the `my-lib` path declared on this file.

Solution: remove/check any configuration in your `paths` in `tsconfig.app.json` to extend properly the `tsconfig.base.json`

```
my-workspace/
  tsconfig.base.json <--- this file contains all libraries declared
  projects/       
    a-app/        
      tsconfig.app.json <--- Check this file in order to extend properly the tsconfig.base.json
    b-app/
      tsconfig.app.json
    my-lib/
      ...
      src/
```